# Generate Random String Containing Alpha-Numeric and Special Chars?

Tags: java, string, random, passwords

I'm interested in generating a (secure) random String with the following properties:

1. Atleast 1 upper case letter
2. Atleast 1 lower case letter
3. Atleast 1 digit from 0-9
4. Atleast one special char from chars $&@?<>~!%#

The length of string should be from 12-13 digits/chars long.

I know there is a class in Apache commons that can help generate random Strings however there is no option to include special chars.

I'm also aware of some other similar questions on SO however none of them address exactly these requirements.

I've tried the following so far:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public final class SessionIdentifierGenerator {
  private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

  public String nextSessionId() {
    return 

    new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
      }
    }
```

But it does not contain char set from each of the 4 points.

I also tried:

```
static final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static Random rnd = new Random();

String randomString( int len ) 
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( len );
   for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
      sb.append(AB.charAt( rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
   return sb.toString();
}
```

I know I can modify the String AB to include special chars but there's no way to **guarantee** string will contain Atleast 1 upper, 1 lower, 1 digit and 1 special char.

I'm using Java.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will find yourself with help and answers more quickly if you post examples of what you have tried and direct questions as opposed to overly broad questions such as "What is the best way?"

Comment: Study the Apache code to see how you might modify it "to include special chars."

Comment: @andrewdleach posted some examples..

Comment: Or you could use [correct horse battery staple](https://xkcd.com/936/). ;)

Comment: I'm still waiting.. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way in your case is to generate the random password containing any of allowed symbols, then test whether the criteria met:

```
private static final String symbols = 
     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$&@?<>~!%#";

public static String genPassword(Random r) {
    while(true) {
        char[] password = new char[r.nextBoolean()?12:13];
        boolean hasUpper = false, hasLower = false, hasDigit = false, hasSpecial = false;
        for(int i=0; i<password.length; i++) {
            char ch = symbols.charAt(r.nextInt(symbols.length()));
            if(Character.isUpperCase(ch))
                hasUpper = true;
            else if(Character.isLowerCase(ch))
                hasLower = true;
            else if(Character.isDigit(ch))
                hasDigit = true;
            else
                hasSpecial = true;
            password[i] = ch;
        }
        if(hasUpper && hasLower && hasDigit && hasSpecial) {
            return new String(password);
        }
    }
}
```

According to my tests, number of required iterations rarely exceeds 5 and in more than half tests the first generated password meets the criteria. Though don't force your users to memoize such passwords! Here's how they look like:

```
c3h$oyuKcZZl
Si4e8F4sWjy#i
V$9WwW7zJ8ba
~9htwMwcFc!s
wBm94~AH%z%MU
p4TE36S&Y>J14
R9Bsqq@23eYk
PTfcvR5u?piZQ
CE8ot>a74PmZP
4zAco~P6Xuf3E
aiv?VDN4j9pE
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an array/list/whatever of characters.  Pick a random lowercase letter and put it into your array.  Pick a random uppercase letter and put it into your array.  Pick a random digit and put it into your array.  Pick a random special character and put it into your array.  You have four characters in your array which partly meets your requirements.

Now pick as many more characters as you need at random from the string: "A-Za-z0-9$&@?<>~!%#"  Add each selected character to your character array.

Now shuffle your character array to mess up the order of the first four characters.

Convert the shuffled array to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The following works well for me. Note, that you could pass in a specific `Random` implementation if you didn't want to use `RandomUtils`.

```java
public class RandomUtil {

    public static final String ALPHABETIC_UPPERCASE_SYMBOLS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static final String ALPHABETIC_LOWERCASE_SYMBOLS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static final String NUMERIC_SYMBOLS = "0123456789";
    public static final String SPECIAL_SYMBOLS = "$&@?<>~!%#";

    public static final String ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPECIAL_SYMBOLS =
            ALPHABETIC_UPPERCASE_SYMBOLS + 
            ALPHABETIC_LOWERCASE_SYMBOLS + 
            NUMERIC_SYMBOLS + 
            SPECIAL_SYMBOLS;


    public static String generateRandomAlphanumericAndSpecialCharactersKey(int length) {
        List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>(length);
        boolean hasUpper = false;
        boolean hasLower = false;
        boolean hasNumber = false;
        boolean hasSpecial = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            // Make sure we have at least one upper, lower, number and special character.
            // Then, fill randomly from set containing all characters.
            if (!hasUpper) {
                chars.add(ALPHABETIC_UPPERCASE_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, ALPHABETIC_UPPERCASE_SYMBOLS.length())));
                hasUpper = true;
            } else if (!hasLower) {
                chars.add(ALPHABETIC_LOWERCASE_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, ALPHABETIC_LOWERCASE_SYMBOLS.length())));
                hasLower = true;
            } else if (!hasNumber) {
                chars.add(NUMERIC_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, NUMERIC_SYMBOLS.length())));
                hasNumber = true;
            } else if (!hasSpecial) {
                chars.add(SPECIAL_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, SPECIAL_SYMBOLS.length())));
                hasSpecial = true;
            } else {
                chars.add(ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPECIAL_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPECIAL_SYMBOLS.length())));
            }
        }

        // Shuffle characters to mix up the first 4 characters
        Collections.shuffle(chars);

        return StringUtils.join(chars, "");
    }

}
```